# Retrofit post request returns 405 error

Tags: android, post, retrofit

I'm new at using retrofit library. I need to write a method that will register user.

Api is shown below:

POST http://blablabla.com/user/
it contains 4 fields

1. fio - string
2. email - string
3. phone - string
4. password - string

Response example:

```
{
    "result": {
        "code": 200,
        "token": "fcac1a3b62cb51374123de565dc12e16"
    }
}
```

It is my client class:

```
package com.example.bydlokoder.mobigeartest.activities.utils;

import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.http.Body;
import retrofit.http.POST;

public class BlaBlaClient {
    public static final String API_URL = "http://blablabla.com/";

    public interface Service {
        @POST("/user")
        void createUser(@Body User user, Callback<Result> callback);
    }
}
```

It is result class that object i wanna get after registration is completed:

```
public class Result {
    int code;
    String token;

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

It is a User class that should be used to create a request:

```
public class User {

    public User(String fio, String email, String phone, String password) {
        this.fio = fio;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.password = password;
    }

    private String fio;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String password;

    public String getFio() {
        return fio;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you have "user" annotated with Body? Is web API requires JSON-serialzied input or urlencoded?